# How to make my word go to second row in table content using Tabularx?

Tags: tables, spacing

How to make the words go to second line without being automatically put a '-'?
For example:

`Example` --> `Ex- ample`

I had tried to adjust the table length, still cannot. I prefer to use `tabularx`

I tried `\space` but it look weird.

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs, ragged2e}   

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}c X c c c c c }
      \toprule
           & & \multicolumn{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{8em}}{\textbf{95\% Confidence Interval of the Difference}}  &  \textbf{t}
           & \textbf {df} 
           & \textbf {Sig.(2-tailed)}  \\
     \cmidrule{3-4}  
           & & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Lower}} &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Upper}} & & &\\
     \midrule
           Pair 1 & Fruit Fruit Example Dataset (AA) - Fruit Fruit Example Dataset (BB) & 34.33\% &  34.33\% & 34.33 & 34.33 & 34.33\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please clarify what you're trying to achieve for the material in the second, `X`-type column. E.g., are you trying to achieve both automatic line wrapping and suppress hyphenation?

Comment: @Mico, thanks. I do not want automatically do hyphenation for all my content in table and words.

Comment: In that case, just use [David's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/504259/5001) while replacing `\RaggedRight` with `\raggedright`, i.e., write `>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X` for the column(s) in question.

Comment: @Mico, thanks. I did try it yesterday. Unfortunately, it making the `column 1` which is `Pair  1` in this example to be very large and making it looks not nice. also making the `column 2` to be smaller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would reorganize the `tabularx` environment as follows:

- First and foremost, and as already suggested in David Carlisle's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/504259/5001), change `>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}c` to `c` and change `X` to either `>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X` (if hyphenation is permissible) or `>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X` (if it is not).
- Decrease the value of the parameter, `\tabcolsep`, which governs the amount of intercolumn whitespace, by a third (from the default value of `6pt` to `4pt`).
- Trim off the unneeded whitespace padding to the left of the first column and to the right or the final column.
- Don't use **boldface** for the header cells -- it's not needed to make an impact, but it does take up a lot of scarce space.
- Use abbreviations in one of the header cells.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}   
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\newcommand\smalltab[1]{%
   \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}#1 \end{tabular}}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt} % default value: 6pt
%%%\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} c L *{5}{c} @{}}
\toprule
& & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\smalltab{95\% Conf.\ Int.\\ of Difference}}  & $t$ & df & \smalltab{Significance\\(2-tailed)} \\
\cmidrule(lr){3-4}  
& & Lower & Upper \\
\midrule
Pair 1 & Fruit Fruit Example Dataset (AA) -- Fruit Fruit Example Dataset (BB) 
& 34.33\% &  34.33\% & 34.33 & 34.33 & 34.33\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

`c` is a single line entry so you can not do

```
>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}c
```

The `\RaggedRight` does nothing, however you want the second, `X` column to be ragged right so replace `X` by

```
>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X
```

Comment: Thanks. I seemed cannot find the meaning of `c` and `X`. I only found `l` for left, `r` for right, `c` for centre.

Comment: Information on the `X` ty column can be found in the manual of the `tabularx` package.

Comment: @leandriis, thanks. `X` = The column(s) specified with this specifier will be stretched to make the table as wide as specified, greatly simplifying the creation of tables.